# PartialView to create a select box: How to Html.Encode Output?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, razor-2

I have this partial view:

```
@model Dictionary<int, string>

<select style="height: 17px;">
  <option value=''></option>
  @foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> value in Model)
  {
    <option value='@Html.Encode(value.Key.ToString())'>
      @Html.Encode(value.Value)
    </option>
  }
</select>
```

Works fine, but if there are e.g. German umlauts in the value it is displayed wrong: [image]

So instead of `ö` there is `&#246;`.

If I use `@value.Value` instead of `@Html.Encode(value.Value)` it works but I want to Html.Encode the values from a database because of security reasons.

Comment: Just use `@value.Value` with using `@` razor will automatically HTML encodes for you. Just check the source of your page. What you see when you are writing  `@Html.Encode(value.Value)` is the case of double encodeing...

Comment: Outsch, yes, I remember. You're right, razor automatically HTML encodes, I forgot. Thanks a lot! (If you repeat your comment as answer I will accept it.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to manually `Html.Encode` because Razor secure by this manner. This means that Razor HTML encodes every string what you write to the output with the `@` sing.

So you can just safely write `@value.Value`.

By the way the effect what you are seeing is the case of the **double encoding** because you first encode for text with `Html.Encode` and then Razor encodes the already encoded text for the second time when you write it out with `@Html.Encode(value.Value)`.